# Ajax combobox extender : Placeholder not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

We are using Ajax Extender Combobox in an ASP.NET project. All our textbox tools are presented with placeholder attribute. But Ajax Combobox neither supports nor throws the error for placeholder attribute.

 Any way, we needed help in using Placeholder attribute for Ajax Combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a fancy, or even proper, way to achieve this using Reflection, etc. I needed a quick and dirty solution, so I used the browser's inspector to determine the ID of the ComboBox's textbox. In my case, I have a placeholder in my Master page called MainContent, so the ID turned out to be MainContent_ComboBox1_ComboBox1_TextBox. Using a little jQuery, I implemented a basic ID Selector statement that changed the placeholder attribute of the textbox control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#MainContent_ComboBox1_ComboBox1_TextBox").attr("placeholder", "hello");
</script>
```